# Problem with propose a custom transaction (for ERC-20 token)

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I have a problem with creating a custom transaction proposal.
Here is my code:

```js
import { ethers, utils } from 'ethers';
import SafeApiKit from '@safe-global/api-kit';
import EthersAdapter from '@safe-global/safe-ethers-lib';
import Safe from '@safe-global/safe-core-sdk';
import { SafeTransactionDataPartial } from '@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types';
import { DefenderRelayProvider, DefenderRelaySigner } from 'defender-relay-client/lib/ethers';

const txServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/txs/';
const safeAddress = '0x512560bB71b98a60bC7e87719D2B8573C935Ff58';
const tokenAddress = '0xFAA27935213A149c5f81442C30BaaD36b15863A9';
const abi = 'erc-20 token abi...';
const amount = '100'; // 100 erc-20 tokens to burn

const {
    API_KEY,
    API_SECRET,
} = process.env;

// Create defender signer:
const credentials = { apiKey: API_KEY!, apiSecret: API_SECRET! };
const relayerProvider = new DefenderRelayProvider(credentials);
const signerOrProvider = new DefenderRelaySigner(credentials, relayerProvider, {
    speed: 'fast'
});

// Create safeService instance:
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
    ethers,
    signerOrProvider
});
const safeService = new SafeApiKit({
    txServiceUrl,
    ethAdapter
});

// Create transactoin description:
const contractInterface = new utils.Interface(abi);
const data = contractInterface.encodeFunctionData('burn', [ethers.utils.parseEther(amount)]);

const safeTransactionData: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
    to: tokenAddress,
    value: '0',
    data,
    operation: 0
};

// Create transaction:
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
    ethAdapter,
    safeAddress
});
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({ safeTransactionData });

// Try to propose transaction:
const safeTxHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
const senderSignature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash);
await safeService.proposeTransaction({
    safeAddress,
    safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
    safeTxHash,
    senderAddress: await signerOrProvider.getAddress(),
    senderSignature: senderSignature.data
});

console.log('DONE!!!!');
```

But when i try to run this code with `ts-node` i get an error:

```
Error: Unprocessable Entity
    at sendRequest (/home/msolovyev/crypto-projects/safe-test/node_modules/@safe-global/api-kit/src/utils/httpRequests.ts:58:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async proposeBurnFromMultisig (/home/msolovyev/crypto-projects/safe-test/src/multisigs.ts:96:5)
```

Please tell me how to correctly calculate the value of the **data** property for a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few things that might cause your problem, an incorrect transaction data or an incorrect environment setup, first verify that `safeAddress` and `tokenAddress` are correct, then check that the ABI you are using is correct for the ERC-20 token you are interacting with, get more detailed error by replacing this

```
await safeService.proposeTransaction({
    safeAddress,
    safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
    safeTxHash,
    senderAddress: await signerOrProvider.getAddress(),
    senderSignature: senderSignature.data
});
```

by this

```
try {
    await safeService.proposeTransaction({
        safeAddress,
        safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
        safeTxHash,
        senderAddress: await signerOrProvider.getAddress(),
        senderSignature: senderSignature.data
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while proposing transaction:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
}
```

you can also check your local Gnosis Safe Transaction Service and that it is reachable at `http://localhost:8000` check also that your API key and secret are valid.

edit: the error `Error while proposing transaction: Unprocessable Entity` mean  the API request you are making contains malformed data or is missing required fields, lets debug further, check `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET` are being loaded correctly

```
console.log('API Key:', API_KEY);
console.log('API Secret:', API_SECRET);
```

also

```
console.log('Safe Address:', safeAddress);
console.log('Token Address:', tokenAddress);
```

be sure that there is no incorrect or missing information, if that persist reach out to Gnosis Safe team for assistance

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it didn't work for me.  Tx service is available, **safeAddress** and **tokenAddress** is correct. ABI is correct. The error message is: Error while proposing transaction: Unprocessable Entity

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: All parameters are filled, the request goes to the service, but come back with 422 error:
{
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/txs/api/v1/safes/0x512560bB71b98a60bC7e87719D2B8573C935Ff58/multisig-transactions/',
    status: 422,
    statusText: 'Unprocessable Entity',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}

Comment: there is still an issue with the data being sent in the API request

Comment: I found out that the problem is in the defender signer.  
If you use the code, 
```javascript
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
    const signerOrProvider = new ethers.Wallet(DEVELOPER_WALLET_KEY!, provider);
```
then everything works. So, I have to go to OpenZeppelin)

Comment: The problem was that Defender provides relayer addresses in non-checksummed form.
Safe API requires exactly this [address format](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/4979741-checksummed-address).
So, if you replace the code with this, then everything works perfectly:
```javascript
import Web3 from 'web3';
// ..
let senderAddress = await signerOrProvider.getAddress();
if (!Web3.utils.checkAddressChecksum(senderAddress)) {
    senderAddress = Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(senderAddress);
}
// ...
await safeService.proposeTransaction({
// ...
    senderAddress
// ...
});
```